# Выползает ошибка Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($search)

Tags: php, mysqli

Подскажите пожалуйста как поправить, я в этом деле новичок. На сайте появляется ошибка
Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($search)

вот сам код ниже:

```
{
$text = str_replace($this->bb_open, '', $text);
$text = str_replace($this->bb_close, '', $text);
$text = str_replace($this->bb_single, '', $text);
$text = preg_replace('#\\[(code|url|img|html)[^\s]*?\].*?\[/\\1\]#usi', '', $text);
return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для текущей версии PHP больше нельзя первым параметром передавать `null` в функцию `str_replace`

Как минимум можно лечить так: `str_replace($this->bb_open ?? '', '', $text);`, т.е. за счёт null coelesce оператора задавать дефолтное значение, если значение `null`.

---

> я в этом деле новичок

Как читать "Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #1"

- Deprecated - тип предупреждения, в данном случае "Устарело"
- `str_replace` - где именно что-то не так.  В данном случае в указанной функции
- Passing null to parameter #1" --- говорит что именно не так. Если вбить текст в переводчик, то тот напишет, что "передача значения null в параметр с номером 1"

Comment: Спасибо вроде получилось

Comment: Галочку слева от ответа тык %)